# TeXstudio citation autocomplete not working with universal bib in texmf-local

Tags: natbib, texstudio

I'm using the latest version of texlive on windows 10 with the latest version of texstudio (2.12.2). I've placed my universal library.bib file in C:\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bib\local and run texhash; so far so good.

Now if I create a tex file anywhere like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ouharvard}          % This is a custom bst I put in C:\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bst\local
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Blencowe2010}

    \bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

Where Blencowe2010 is in my library.bib database, it works fine, however upon typing \cite{ I get no autocomplete suggestions and have to type the entry in by hand - this is an issue that google tells me used to exist in texstudio, but apparently got fixed a couple of years ago. I've found that changing the bibliography line to:

```
\bibliography{/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib/local/library}
```

Will solve this issue, but from what I understand this shouldn't be required. Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own issue. Firstly in tex documents, paths must be expressed with forward slashes, else tex interprets them as commands. Next I had to go to "Options > Configure TeXstudio > Adv. Editor" and scroll down on this window. Under "Additional Search Paths > Bib Files" I added "C:\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bib\local" (no quotes).